# How to change the value of two hidden fields with the same id and name jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this fields

```
<input type="hidden" id="uidhcdm" name="uidhcdm" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="uidhcdm" name="uidhcdm" value="0">
```

and i am using a function called change val

```
function changeval(x,val)
{ 
    $('#'+x).val(val);
}
```

but when i run the function it only affects the first hidden fields value but not the seconds!

Please help me !!

Comment: You shouldn't have two fields with the same id!

Comment: You should not have two elements with the same ID. Select by `class` in cases like this.

Comment: You can't have more than 1 element with the same id, results are unpredictable. Use class instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to recognize that the attribute "id" of a tag has to be unique. You can define more elements with the same value for "id" but every DOM access will only retrieve the first one, since, by definition, only one elements is allowed to have one specific id.
Other words: having the same id for more than one element is malformed code.

Answer (score 3):

ID should be unique. Change `id` to `class`:

```
<input type="hidden" class="uidhcdm" name="uidhcdm" value="0">
<input type="hidden" class="uidhcdm" name="uidhcdm" value="0">
```

Then change `#` to `.` in `changeval()`:

```
function changeval(x,val) { 
    $('.'+x).val(val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could put the input fields in a div container, e.g.

```
<div id="View">
<input type="hidden" id="uidhcdm" name="uidhcdm" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="uidhcdm" name="uidhcdm" value="0">
</div>
```

then use something like?

```
function changeval(x,val) {
$("#View > input").each(function () {
if ($(this).id===x) {
    $(this).val(val);
}})};
```

I'm pretty sure this will work, or a minor modification fo it should.

Comment: not that I advocate having the same id for elements... I'm not sure if the === operator will work properly